# Why does GeoWebCache integrated in GeoServer return black images from http TMS requests?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, geoserver, tms

I'm trying to use the GeoWebCache integrated in to GeoServer (2.0.2) to make http request to receive PNG's of tiles using this form:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/osm/131936/86527/18.png
```

I'm fairly sure the server is receiving this request and returning a blank PNG file, and my guess is that it's because the tile isn't already cached.

I'm trying to find a way to get the server to generate the tiles on request but with no Joy, and I'm not certain that's even the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I resolved by clearing the Resource Cache [image]

If anyone is interested, the full debugging steps is documented [here](https://www.mishari.net/2015/02/geoserver-geocache-tms-blank-tiles/).